# How can I access proxy prompt in chrome browser

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, alert, undetected-chromedriver

I am using an undetected chrome browser with proxy

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
host_ip='X.XXX.XXX.XXX'
port='XXXXX'
ipCheckURL = "http://whatismyipaddress.com"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(host_ip + ":" + port))
ucdriver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options, use_subprocess=True)
ucdriver.get(ipCheckURL)
time.sleep(333)
```

When I start automation proxy prompt/alert pops up
[image]

I want to access the prompt/alert

```
# Store the alert in a variable for reuse
alert = Alert(driver)

# Type your message
alert.send_keys("username\n")
alert.send_keys("password\n")

# Press the OK button
alert.accept()
```

The [selenium alert driver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/alerts/) works for a [common alert](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/tryit.php/WXYeMD9tD4) but does not seem to access the proxy prompt/alert!

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert
```

The reason I want to access this prompt/alert is that I want to run headless chrome in the undetected-chrome browser.

Passing the username and password in proxy did not work with an undetected chrome browser.

```
options = {
            'proxy': {
                'http': f'http://{Username}:{password}@{Ip}:{port}',
                'https': f'https://{Username}:{password}@{Ip}:{port}',
                'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
            }
        }

        seleniumwire_options = {'proxy': {f'http': f'http://{Username}:{password}@{Ip}:{port}',
                                          f'https': f'https://{Username}:{password}@{Ip}:{port}'},
                                'disable_encoding': True, 'verify_ssl': False,
                                'ignore_http_methods': ['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS']}
```

Is there any way I can access the proxy authentication alert in headless mode?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @faaizhashmi can you share the page url with us

Comment: thanks I have updated the post. Added the URL in the code.